# In matplotlib, how do you draw R-style axis ticks that point outward from the axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Because they are drawn inside the plot area, axis ticks are obscured by the data in many matplotlib plots. A better approach is to draw the ticks extending from the axes *outward*, as is the default in `ggplot`, R's plotting system.

In theory, this can be done by redrawing the tick lines with the `TICKDOWN` and `TICKLEFT` line-styles for the x-axis and y-axis ticks respectively:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mplticker
import matplotlib.lines as mpllines

# Create everything, plot some data stored in `x` and `y`
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
plt.plot(x, y)

# Set position and labels of major and minor ticks on the y-axis
# Ignore the details: the point is that there are both major and minor ticks
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mplticker.MultipleLocator(1.0))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(mplticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mplticker.MultipleLocator(1.0))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mplticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))

# Try to set the tick markers to extend outward from the axes, R-style
for line in ax.get_xticklines():
    line.set_marker(mpllines.TICKDOWN)

for line in ax.get_yticklines():
    line.set_marker(mpllines.TICKLEFT)

# In real life, we would now move the tick labels farther from the axes so our
# outward-facing ticks don't cover them up

plt.show()
```

But in practice, that's only half the solution because the `get_xticklines` and `get_yticklines` methods return only the *major* tick lines. The minor ticks remain pointing inward.

What's the work-around for the minor ticks?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your matplotlib config file, matplotlibrc, you can set:

```
xtick.direction      : out     # direction: in or out
ytick.direction      : out     # direction: in or out
```

and this will draw both the major and minor ticks *outward* by default, like R. For a single program, simply do:

```
>> from matplotlib import rcParams
>> rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
>> rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the minors in at least two ways:

```
>>> ax.xaxis.get_ticklines() # the majors
<a list of 20 Line2D ticklines objects>
>>> ax.xaxis.get_ticklines(minor=True) # the minors
<a list of 38 Line2D ticklines objects>
>>> ax.xaxis.get_minorticklines()
<a list of 38 Line2D ticklines objects>
```

Note that the 38 is because minor tick lines have also been drawn at the "major" locations by the MultipleLocator call.